# Bootstrap modal not showing all values passed to it

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a Bootstrap site. I have text areas, and when you click "Post" it should display a modal with the elements you passed in. Most of them seem to be working but I'm having the following issues:

- The "Name" box is showing "[object HTMLTextAreaElement]" instead of showing a value
- Date and Price causes the modal to not show, with the following error:
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

I'm updating them using JavaScript, calling a `showPreview()` function on button click.

The following is the code for the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="previewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="previewModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="previewModalTitle">Your Newstream Preview</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <h3 id="previewNewstreamTitle"></h3>
          <h3 id="previewJournalistName"></h3>
          <h4 id="previewNewstreamDate"></h4>
          <p id="previewNewstreamSummary"></p>
          <h3 id="previewDispatchTitle">f</h3>
          <p id="previewDispatch">f</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Publish Newstream</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following is the code for Date and Price boxes:

```
var newstreamTitle = document.getElementById("newstreamTitleBox").value;
document.getElementById("previewNewstreamTitle").innerHTML = newstreamTitle;

var newstreamSummary = document.getElementById("addNewstreamSummaryBox").value;
document.getElementById("previewNewstreamSummary").innerHTML = newstreamSummary;

var author = document.getElementById("journoNameBox");
document.getElementById("previewJournalistName").innerHTML = author;

var date = document.getElementById("articleDateBox").value;
document.getElementById("previewNewstreamDate").innterHTML = date;

var price = document.getElementById("articlePriceBox").value;
document.getElementById("previewArticlePrice").innerHTML = price;

var dispatchTitle = document.getElementById("dispatchTitleBox").value;
document.getElementById("previewDispatchTitle").innerHTML = dispatchTitle;

var dispatch = document.getElementById("addDispatchBox").value;
document.getElementById("previewDispatch").innerHTML = dispatch;

$('#previewModal').modal('toggle');
```

Lastly, this is the JS for updating the modal body:

```
var newstreamTitle = document.getElementById("newstreamTitleBox").value;
document.getElementById("previewNewstreamTitle").innerHTML = newstreamTitle;

var newstreamSummary = document.getElementById("addNewstreamSummaryBox").value;
document.getElementById("previewNewstreamSummary").innerHTML = newstreamSummary;

var author = document.getElementById("journoNameBox");
document.getElementById("previewJournalistName").innerHTML = author;

var date = document.getElementById("articleDateBox").value;
document.getElementById("previewNewstreamDate").innterHTML = date;

var price = document.getElementById("articlePriceBox").value;
document.getElementById("previewArticlePrice").innerHTML = price;

var dispatchTitle = document.getElementById("dispatchTitleBox").value;
document.getElementById("previewDispatchTitle").innerHTML = dispatchTitle;

var dispatch = document.getElementById("addDispatchBox").value;
document.getElementById("previewDispatch").innerHTML = dispatch;

$('#previewModal').modal('toggle');
```

Comment: You need to provide your JS.

Comment: Your JS code for name is missing the `.value`. It should be `var author = document.getElementById("journoNameBox").value;` like all your other selectors. As for the price and date. I do not see "previewArticlePrice" or "previewNewstreamDate" in your HTML. Also you mispelled innerHTML when you are setting the date.